# iPhone - get values of UITextField which are placed in customized UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Normally I have labels and some text fields which are IBOutlets and if someone clicks a button, I can read the text values of these textfields easily with

```
self.myTextfield1.text;
```

But now I have a `UITableView` with customized table cells. In these cells I have a label and a textfield. On load, I do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (!cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.myCell;
            self.myCell = nil;
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.myCellLabel.text = @"Label1";
                cell.myCellTextField.text = @"...";
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.myCellLabel.text = @"Label2";
                cell.myCellTextField.text = @"...";
                break;
            // and so on...
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.myCellLabel.text = @"Label1_1";
                cell.myCellTextField.text = @"...";
                break;
            // and so on...
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

So If someone clicks the button, I cannot access the text values of the fields with `self.mytextfield1.text`. How can I get the value of the fields? I know in which section and which row which value for a label should be. So if I can get the value of the text field in combination of the section and row number this would be great.

Perhaps anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the values of the textfields in an array then the index of the array would be the same as the row. You could even have multiple arrays:
`cellLabelArray`
`cellTextFieldArray`
which isn't terribly elegant but would solve the problem. Then you would get rid of your switch statement and do something like this:

```
cell.myCellLabel.text = [cellLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath:row];
cell.myTextField.text = [cellTextFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath:row];
```

Using an array to be the datasource of a UITableView is a common pattern.

I don't know what happens when your button gets pressed, but if you need to change the values of the labels, you would just change the values in the array and then send the tableview a `reloadData` message.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the table cells are reused, so you cannot 'pull' the entered values from the cells, rather let the cells 'push' the entered values to you using the UITextFieldDelegate.

In the custom UITableViewCell, add variables for section and row, set the cell to the textfield delegate and forward the resulting textfield events to your viewcontroller with the additional section and row by using a custom delegate protocol. Then lets the viewcontroller write the incoming data to the same place as the UITableView datasource reads data.

Here is an example without section but with a 'type':

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ArticleTextFieldViewCellDelegate

-(void)didUpdateTextField:(int)index type:(int)type withText:(NSString*)text;

@end

@interface ArticleTextFieldViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField* valueTextField;

    id<ArticleTextFieldViewCellDelegate> delegate;

    int index;
    int type;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* valueTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ArticleTextFieldViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int index;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int type;

@end
```

and implementation

```
#import "ArticleTextFieldViewCell.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation ArticleTextFieldViewCell

@synthesize type, valueTextField, delegate, index;

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if(delegate) {
        [delegate didUpdateTextField:index type:type withText:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // optionally trigger delegate method here
}

@end
```

If more than one textfield per cell, use more delegate methods or an additional variable like the 'type'.

Comment: I like this organization, it makes much more sense than going through gyrations trying to pull the values from the text fields.   You have to be careful though, still, if your tables can reorder and delete rows, of the coherency of the row and section values stored in the custom cells.    Also, you should emphasize the need to create the custom cell class for your solution, the OP may not have one, you don't need to create one in order to use that particular loading-custom-cell-from-nib pattern.

Comment: as Walter responds, your datasource also needs some tuning. Use an Array of Arrays if you want multiple sections and rows.